# Creating nanocomposite with material studio

Tags: density-functional-theory

I need to create ZnO/ graphene sheet nanocomposite with material studio and i dont know how. Please, help me or guide me to some one who can help me. I'm blocked.

Comment: by a sheet nanocomposite, are you referring to building graphene layer with another layer of ZnO above it? like a vdW heterostructure?

Comment: I want to insert ZnO nanoparticules into graphene sheet surface

Comment: You don't really give enough information for us to help you. Is it literally that you don't know how to use Materials Studio? It comes with an extensive set of tutorials and help functionality, with more on the BIOVIA community site. Or is it that you don't know what the actual initial structure should be?